# Why does my GeoJSON have no coordinates when saving from Shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geojson

I've got a shapefile (`.shp`, `.shx`, `.dbf`, and `.prj`) that I'm trying to save as a GeoJSON using QGIS 2.14. When I load the `.shp` into QGIS, everything seems to work fine, the Shapefile renders properly.

[image: QGIS Shapefile]

However, when I try to do a `Save As` and select GeoJSON, I get `null` values for all my GeoJSON coordinate values.

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Section": null, "Block": "Last Name, First Name" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": null } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Section": null, "Block": "Last Name, First Name" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": null } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Section": null, "Block": "Last Name, First Name" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": null } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Section": null, "Block": "Last Name, First Name" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": null } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Section": null, "Block": "Last Name, First Name" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": null } },
etc, etc..............
```

Is there something special I need to do to make sure my coordinates show up when I'm saving my data?

Comment: Does the original data have a valid coordinate system defined in the prj file?

Comment: It does. This is the `.prj` file: `GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]`

Comment: Strange. This isn't quite an answer (doesn't solve it in QGIS), but you could use the ogr2ogr command line tool (included in QGIS, see http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to convert from shapefile to GeoJSON, hopefully without this issue.

Comment: I've tried `ogr2ogr` as well, but still no luck. I get `Warning 1: Infinite or NaN coordinate encountered` for every geometry, then a geojson like the one above

Comment: Capture some coordinates with ogrinfo -al your_shapefile.shp.

Comment: [Here is a snippet of the `ogrinfo -al`](https://gist.github.com/briandaviddavidson/473a730046984bd68f421ebee98a0b69). There are coordinates, but there is a `nan` value that I think is the `z` value. Would that affect it?

Comment: Maybe, try forcing 2D with `-dim 2` in ogr2ogr. Example: `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -dim 2 output_2D.shp input_3D.shp` like suggested [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101358/exporting-to-2d-arcview-3-0-compatible-shapefile-in-qgis)

Comment: Yup, I bet it's that nan z value making ogr (which I think is what QGIS uses internally anyway) unhappy.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will give that a shot when I'm home.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use ogr2ogr @ machine, could also use web client for this transformation .shp to GeoJSON-
https://ogre.adc4gis.com/